# filters inside django trans tag : first translates then applies filters; unlike other tags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters, django-i18n

I encountered a weird behavior from django `trans` tag. As you know whenever we use a filter inside a tag, the filter first applies and then gives the result as input to the tag. But this is in reverse order for trans tag.

Example:

Suppose I have this django.po file:

```
msgid "msgid-world"
msgstr "world"

msgid "msgid-"
msgstr "message"
```

Now see the result of these tags:

```
{% trans "msgid-"|add:"world" %}
result: messageworld  (first translate then concat)
```

Expected result: "world" (first concat then translate the key)

**UPDATE**:

My problem is about consistency. The behavior with other tags (like "if") is converse!

Moreover if I write a custom tag for myself like below:

```
@register.simple_tag
def customtrans(a):
    return _(str(a))
```

then it will behave like other tags. The result of this example (like the above example):

```
{% customtrans "msgid-"|add:"world" %}
```

will be "world".

This is the mysterious point I want to understand!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/?highlight=pipe#filters)

> Variables can be modified by filters. Filters are separated from the variable by a pipe symbol (|) and may have optional arguments in parentheses. Multiple filters can be chained. The output of one filter is applied to the next

So it does what described:

1. evaluates `trans` with the argument "msgid-"
2. passes the result to the next filter and adds "world"

I suggest you're using [blocktrans](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) for your puropse

```
{% load i18n %}
{% blocktrans %}
    msgid-world
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Or you could use a with statement:

```
{% with variable="msgid-"|add:"world"}
    {% trans variable %}
{% endwith%}
```

Also check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/ for a ton of options how you could solve your problem

Comment: "...whenever we use a filter inside a tag, the filter first applies and then gives the result as input to the tag."  I only know this because I just learned it the hard way.  Can you point me to where this is documented?  I searched and couldn't find any reference to this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, I analysed the django implementation of `simple_tag` and `trans`:

The important parts of the analysis are:

1. Using `simple_tag` and `trans`, both eventually will have the same `FilterExpression` https://github.com/django/django/blob/e3d546a1d986f83d8698c32e13afd048b65d06eb/django/template/library.py#L123

   ```
   (Pdb) l
   119                     args, kwargs = parse_bits(
   120                         parser, bits, params, varargs, varkw, defaults,
   121                         kwonly, kwonly_defaults, takes_context, function_name,
   122                     )
   123  ->                 return SimpleNode(func, takes_context, args, kwargs, target_var)
   (Pdb) print(args)
   [<django.template.base.FilterExpression object at 0x1061e5cf8>]
   (Pdb) print(args[0].__dict__)
   {'token': '"msgid-"|add:"world"', 'filters': [(<function add at 0x10c2369d8>, [(False, 'world')])], 'var': 'msgid-'}
   ```

   ```
   (Pdb) l
   368         message_context = None
   369         seen = set()
   370         invalid_context = {'as', 'noop'}
   371
   372  ->     while remaining:
   373             option = remaining.pop(0)
   374             if option in seen:
   376                 raise TemplateSyntaxError(
   377                     "The '%s' option was specified more than once." % 
   (Pdb) message_string.__dict__
   {'token': '"msgid-"|add:"world"', 'filters': [(<function add at 0x1112a79d8>, [(False, 'world')])], 'var': 'msgid-'}
   ```
2. But now the implementation differs

   While `simple_tag` is using `SimpleNode`, which first resolves the arguments (https://github.com/django/django/blob/e3d546a1d986f83d8698c32e13afd048b65d06eb/django/template/library.py#L191) before it get passed to your function,  `trans` uses it's own `TranslationNode` (https://github.com/django/django/blob/e3d546a1d986f83d8698c32e13afd048b65d06eb/django/templatetags/i18n.py#L68) implementation, which behaves differently.

**Consistency**
First this was interesting to dig into, since I was not aware of the different behavior.

In the end it's a implementation detail, which is based upon the author's taste.
`simple_tag` is implemented that way and it's also described in the code https://github.com/django/django/commit/655f52491505932ef04264de2bce21a03f3a7cd0#diff-258b66ed22ebadbcfec255f802c95bdfR173-R176 - Maybe the doc string could be a bit more explicit.

With `trans` and `blocktrans` you basically can go both ways, pre populated or not.

You can still use `tag` instead of `simple_tag` and implement it differently.

I haven't found anything about a guideline where to follow jinja2-filters logic or not. This was a false assumption from my side.